# Host FTP/File Manager on site

Tags: files

I've NEVER been a fan of plugging a ftp address in a browser to access the files from a ftp server. I am trying to find a find a module  to allow drupal to host a FTP/File Manager. Example would be ANY host like Godaddy having a  File Manager in their CPanel.

I would rather use this module for FTP Access (allowing user to plug in username/password), which would allow them to reach a ftp server. Then give them the drag and drop functionality of Filezila, but all of this hosted on a Drupal site.

EDIT: Let me clarify that I am not looking for a ftp manager to upload drupal files. I am looking for a module that will act like Filezilla, in the fact that anonymous users can put in **any FTP address**, followed by username/password, then access the files on THAT FTP SERVER (from their Drupal site).

Comment: Did you try [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce)?

Comment: or https://drupal.org/project/filebrowser ?

Comment: I saw filebrowser, but I'm not to sure it will act like a ftp manager. Meaning that a anonymous user can insert their FTP SERVER credentials (NOT drupal credentials) from our drupal site. The point is for our clients to access our FTP Server through our Drupal site. Drupal site will be on a different server then FTP Server.

Comment: SO with filebrowser or IMCE, could I specifies the FTP Server address, then enter my FTP username/password. Do they support SFTP? I'll look at them, but if you know, please let me know.

Comment: IMCE does not use FTP at all. You can also configure different profiles with various access permissions.

Comment: Well I need FTP client inside the module.